# Lulu Publishers Api has been discontinued, what to do now?

Tags: php, api, curl, simulate

I was starting to work with the LULU api and was trying to automate the whole process through our website, dont know why but they have discontinued their service by the end of APRIL this year. Here is a message on thir portal.

http://connect.lulu.com/t5/Frequently-Asked-Questions/Lulu-Developer-Portal-Update/td-p/289614

I tried to work without the API through PHP's curl but they have a very complex form wizard and dont know why its not working. I am now hoping if there is some kind of system which can automate the form submission just like a human.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on what you are trying to accomplish. There are other players in the book world that have automated APIs. Here are some of them:

http://www.createspace.com/

http://www.ondemandbooks.com/

http://www1.lightningsource.com/

The closest matching to what Lulu's APIs used to do is probably Peecho:

http://www.peecho.com/

Answer (score 1):

The old publishing API needed support resources that we couldn't offer at the time unfortunately. The new version is out and has its own support team.
https://api.lulu.com/docs/